# C# - List View being sorted by prefixed icon instead of text

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, listview

I have a C# Windows form that hooks into Active Directory. On this form is a list view that displays the users within a selected OU and includes an indexed icon based on if the account is active or disabled. However, when sorting by name, it seems to be sorting by the icon index rather than the user name:

[image]

This is my code for sorting the columns on header click:

```
        // ================================================================================
        // Handle list header sort
        // ================================================================================
        private void listView_ad_ColumnClick(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.ColumnClickEventArgs e)
        {
            ListView myListView = (ListView)sender;

            if (e.Column == lvwColumnSorter.SortColumn)
            {
                if (lvwColumnSorter.Order == SortOrder.Ascending)
                {
                    lvwColumnSorter.Order = SortOrder.Descending;
                }
                else
                {
                    lvwColumnSorter.Order = SortOrder.Ascending;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lvwColumnSorter.SortColumn = e.Column;
                lvwColumnSorter.Order = SortOrder.Ascending;
            }

            myListView.Sort();
        }
```

How can I go about sorting by the column text content rather than the icon index value?

Comment: What does the debugger tell you about the branch the code takes?

Comment: I can't check as the app need's to run on a Windows domain-joined device (or a DC) and my dev device is not on one.

Comment: Please show the implementation of your `IComparer`